# Find smallest and largest linked values in a many-to-many table relationship

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a chorus management database and need to create a particular query.  (MySQL programming in PHP.)

I have a table of singers and a table of events which have a many-to-many relationship managed by a roster table.  Each roster record links to one SingerID and one EventID.  I would like to create a browse table of the form:

The catch is that some singers may have no events linked.

Is there a way to do this in a single MySQL query, or will I need to write one query to list all my singers, and a second query to list all of the events for each singer, and then examine the second query to extract the first and last records (assuming I sort the last query by date)?

Answer (score 1):

Use a LEFT JOIN that way it doesn't need to exist

Comment: Not sure, nothing to work from so I just pointed in the right direction. MySQL is capable of pulling everything in 1 query when you need to.

Answer (score 0):

I also think the way Mike does, Query should be like this

```
SELECT * FROM singer
LEFT OUTER JOIN roster ON singer.id =roster.singerid
INNER JOIN event ON event.id=roster.eventid
ORDER BY singer.name,singer.date
```

Comment: The date field is in the event table, not the singer table, and I'm hoping to create a single record that shows the earliest event date (and its associated event name) and the latest event date (and its associated event name).  I have no reason to expect that this is possible in a single query; just hopeful.